# strtotime shows current year for previous dates

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

strtotime always shows current year even the date am passing is of past years. I checked with yyyy-mm-dd format and it works properly. The only problem is with my current format which is a text (20th Dec, 2016)

```
$sd = "20th Dec, 2016";
echo strtotime($sd);
```

> Output : 1545354960 (which is GMT: Thursday, December 20, **2018** 2:46:00 PM)

What is wrong here? what is the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strtotime()` function can only convert a limited number of formats, as detailed in the [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) section in the PHP manual.

The following note from the [Date Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) page is pertinent in this case as the `2018` part of your example is interpreted as a 24-hour time value.

> **Note:**
>
> The "Year (and just the year)" format only works if a time string has already been found -- otherwise this format is recognised as HH MM.

You could use string manipulation (e.g. use `preg_replace()` or `str_replace()` to remove the `,`) to provide a date format that PHP interprets as you want. I would prefer using a regex, eg:

```
$sd = "20th Dec, 2016";
echo date("y", strtotime(preg_replace("/([\w ]+),([\w ]+)/", "$1$2", $sd)));
```

A good alternative would be to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), with which you state exactly the format that the date string has.

```
$sd = "20th Dec, 2016";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("dS M, Y", $sd);
echo $dt->format("d-M-Y");
echo strtotime($dt->format("d-M-Y"));
```

Comment: You can also get the timestamp using `$dt->getTimestamp();` in above case but keep in mind that `strtotime` and `$dt->getTimestamp();` will give different results.

Comment: Should also be [mentioned that the format is not subjective](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php): `Note:
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates`

Comment: Using `\DateTime::createFromFormat()` without a specified time will use the current time, where `strtotime` will assume a time of `00:00:00`. You can avoid the different result with `$dt->getTimestamp()` and `strtotime()` by prefixing your format with an exclamation like so: [`!dS M, Y`](https://3v4l.org/1KinF).